# install_bitbucket or install_github and install specific versions of dependencies

Tags: r, devtools, reproducible-research

I have a package hosted on a bitbucket private repository and would like to install my package along with the specific versions of it's dependencies specified in the Depends section of the DESCRIPTION file:

```
Depends: R (>= 2.15.0), foo (== 1.17-12)
```

Is there a way to have devtools automatically find and install foo version 1.17-12 for R 2.15.0?

I like devtools' ability to install different refs (development, master, my-feature-branch, ...etc.) from my bitbucket repo and then install all of it's dependencies, but installing my R package on different servers at different times, means I can easily pick up unwanted dependent package changes and I also need to keep R up to date all of the time in order for it to find all of the packages.

Comment: http://rstudio.github.io/packrat/ might be of some use here, though I don't think it does exactly what you want out of the box.